# Getting lyrics from Musixmatch

Tags: php, arrays, curl

Unfortunately I haven't any experience in coding PHP. Just Html.
I'm trying to retrieve lyrics from Musixmatch without success.
This code below I'd used to retrieve successfully Bios from Last.fm, and to use with Musixmatch I've changed the values (url, api_key).
Can you give me a little help?
Thanks so much.
Merry Xmas.

```
   <?php
   $fields = array(    
         'q_track' => $track,    
         'q_artist' => $artist,    
         'api_key' => 'xxxxxecab2a0072c88ee31b50a4225b');    
$fields_string = '';    
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }    
rtrim($fields_string,'&');    
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  
'http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get');    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; 
Windows NT 5.0)");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
$response = curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);    
$soap = simplexml_load_string($response);    ?>


<div>
<div  />
<h3><?php echo $track; ?></h3>
</div>
<br><div><p><?php print nl2br(strip_tags($soap->body->lyrics- 
>lyrics_body)); ?></p><br></div>
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving? The user agent your are using is quite old.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm receiving an empty response, without errors.
Here is the page where I test the code: http://companyfm.com/lyrics4.php

Comment: Place `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` right underneath your opening `<?php` tag; does it show any errors? @ClaudioMartino

Comment: These are the errors:
    Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag 
   expected, '<' not found in /home/i6mjtazilgjm/public_html/lyrics4.php on line 
    59

    Warning: simplexml_load_string(): {"message":{"header":{"status_code":501,"execute_time":0.00012898445129395},"bod in /home/i6mjtazilgjm/public_html/lyrics4.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/i6mjtazilgjm/public_html/lyrics4.php on line 59

Comment: and: Notice: Trying to get property 'body' of non-object in /home/i6mjtazilgjm/public_html/lyrics4.php on line 65

Notice: Trying to get property 'lyrics' of non-object in /home/i6mjtazilgjm/public_html/lyrics4.php on line 65

Notice: Trying to get property 'lyrics_body' of non-object in /home/i6mjtazilgjm/public_html/lyrics4.php on line 65

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Musixmatch api. You need to use the query input parms (q_*) with the api commands that end with 'search', not get. If you use 'get' you need the ID of the object (ex track_id=#####).  Regards.

example works with 'search' and input of 'q_':
curl:
curl --url "http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?q_artist=Toto&q_track=Rosanna&apikey=########"

---

partial curl output:
{"message":{"header":{"status_code":200,"execute_time":0.020166873931885,"available":26},"body":{"track_list":[{"track":{"track_id":88430107

Answer (score 0):

1/ You're sending the request using `POST` method which is not supported By the API.
Try replacing the `CURL` request by this:

```
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  
'http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get?'.$fields_string);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
$response = curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);
```

2/ The API's response type is `JSON`, so try using `json_decode()` instead of `simplexml_load_string()`

Alos, I recommend using HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've replaced the CURL, don't  show errors, but the response is empty.

Comment: Try adding `print_r($response);` after `curl_close($ch);` to see what is the response of the API

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The response is just numbers that changes when refresh the page. Example: 5010.00019621849060059